# Access Query Problem - Results Not Showing Unless Created In Wizard

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys

I'm creating a pretty simple system for some A-Level ICT coursework. Basically its a system for mechanics to record customers and the vehicles they have worked on. I have five tables with the following primary keys

Table    :  Primary Key  : Foreign Key

Customer :  CustomerID

Employee :  EmployeeID

Vehicle  :  Registration

Part     :  PartID

Fixed Vehicles  :  FixedID  :  Registration  : CustomerID  : PartID  :  EMployeeID

Basically when i create a query unless it is created using a wizard it shows no results even if any criteria are left blank. What i want to be able to do is search for a vehicle via registration and the vehicle make, model and registration be show but also the customers name and if they have paid their bill or not. I'd like to be able to do the same by a customer search too

Here is the database on my dropbox account if it is any help
[Access Database](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11588165/Database1.accdb)

Thanks In Advance - Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things going on here. First, you should be able to create the query in the QBE grid without using the wizard. Second, you only need the Vehicle and Customer table since you are only asking for data from those two. Third, you need to note in the design that the CustomerID foreign key in the Vehicle table is not required (nullable) and thus, you have to assume that a given Vehicle row will not have a CustomerID. To get all Vehicle rows whether they have a customer or not, you need to use a Left Join:

```
SELECT Vehicle.Make, Vehicle.Model, Vehicle.Year, Vehicle.Registration
    , Customer.Forename, Customer.Surname, Customer.Paid
FROM Vehicle
    LEFT JOIN Customer 
        ON Customer.CustomerID = Vehicle.CustomerID;
```

If you wanted to search by Customer whether or not they had a Vehicle and to show the Vehicle information if it exists, you would reverse the join:

```
SELECT Vehicle.Make, Vehicle.Model, Vehicle.Year, Vehicle.Registration
    , Customer.Forename, Customer.Surname, Customer.Paid
FROM Customer 
    LEFT JOIN Vehicle 
        ON Customer.CustomerID = Vehicle.CustomerID;
```

Note however, that since Customer is the parent table in this case, if a given Customer is associated with multiple Vehicle rows, the results will duplicate that Customer's data. I.e., it will show one row for every vehicle to which the Customer is associated (or just the Customer row if they have no Vehicle row associations).

Answer (score 0):

Try using outer joins instead of inner joins.  When you create a join in the query window, you can right-click on the line and get a drop-down menu with 'properties'.

Or, if you prefer, use the sql view to change 'inner' to 'left outer'